# Read only access to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, service

I am creating tool to run SQL queries against a database in a scheduled manner, for some monitoring purpose. How can I restrict a user from updating the database using this tool?

Currently I prevent updating data by running the service under service user with only read-only access. Is any other way to do this? (I want other option because this service user is a shared user. In the future some other developer may want to give this user update permission for other requirements).

I see [ApplicationIntent read only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213002.aspx) option but this not restrict user from updating the database, and i not sure replication is on or not in production SQL Server.

I am using SQL Server 2012 (both tool backend and database to be monitored) and Windows service to run the query against DB.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you using WinAuth or SQLAuth?

Comment: WinAuth (User linked with Active Directory )

Comment: Are you able create a user for your app? If so, use a separate user in your app and use impersonation to login to sql using that user

Comment: another solution is using transaction, so that you start a transaction before running the query in the toll and rollback after executing the query. Note that there are some disadvantages in this case. do that only if your tool supposed to retrieve small result sets. This is not a perfect solution but may work for your case.

Comment: it looks like a good option , but as i already mentioned this application is for other apps health monitoring. i don't know is it effect other application perfomence or make any dead lock in DB

Comment: what if you specify proper isolation level in your tool (like dirty_read)? This way it will not lock data.

Comment: yes that is good. but if some one put commit in sql code , then it will be a issue . thanks for the suggestion, i will try this and come back.

Comment: why don't you setup a service account and in the db give it Read only Permissions this way users can't update it since their individual sql accounts won't have access to doing Updates.. sounds simple enough

Comment: i already using this approach. The issue is that Windows service i use is a common service framework developed by our company (installed and maintained by other team) and we just reusing it , if i want to use separate user then i have to run new service instance (in new server it is not possible)

Answer (score 1):

I generally create a separate database user for each tool/application.  This allows you to specify exactly the permissions you need for each tool without affecting other applications.

You can use the [EXECUTE AS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) statement at the beginning of your transaction to use the restricted permission set while still using your windows service account to connect.

Comment: the Windows service i use is a common service framework developed by our company and we just reusing it , if i want to use separate user then i have to run new instance (in new server it is not possible)

Comment: Have you looked into the [EXECUTE AS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) statement in SQL?  You could create a user on the database with the permissions you need and grant permissions for your service user to impersonate it.

Comment: Not sure if you're already doing this, but I always apply both db_datareader and db_denydatawriter when I create read-only users to make sure the intent is clear.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at user mapping of db_datareader

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

you can give the user by which the tool connects to the DB that user mapping role . making it only able to do SELECT queries

Comment: i already using this approach, as i already mentioned it have some limitations. I looking for some other options.

Comment: if you give that role in your tool's connection string, and in the future some changes that user role , when that user uses your tool he will revert to read only premiision role .  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140245.aspx the Roles section

Comment: i don't get it fully , but i will try this